# Convert Image to Grayscale

Tags: image, colors

How do I convert image to grayscale? I have the following quote from the wikipedia:

> To convert any color to a grayscale
>   representation of its luminance, first
>   one must obtain the values of its red,
>   green, and blue (RGB) primaries in
>   linear intensity encoding, by gamma
>   expansion. Then, add together 30% of
>   the red value, 59% of the green value,
>   and 11% of the blue value

Do I understand this quote correctly? I would do something like this:

```
For each pixel P
    For each color c in P
        P.c = round(
            (max(min((P.red^gamma), 255), 0) * 0.3) + 
            (max(min((P.blue^gamma), 255), 0) * 0.59) +
            (max(min((P.green^gamma), 255), 0) * 0.11))
```

Is it correct? **What should gamma be?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. I will use Gamma 2.2. Depending of what you intend to use this grayscale image after that, Gamma of 1.0 can be faster and useful too.

Answer (score 0):

I've always implemented with gamma = 1.0 (in other words, ignored).

You can find more about gamma correction here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction